# Как изменить формат даты регулярным выражением?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть примеры:

```
20150701
20200806
```

Как разделить на:

```
2015.07.10
2020.08.06
```

00 последние убрать <sub>Прим.ред.: Автор не уточнил, что это значит. Скорее всего, нерелевантно для решения.</sub>

Comment: `00 последние убрать` - можете пояснить?

Answer (score 6):

по-моему, в данном случае лучше использовать `datetime` вместо регулярных выражений:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

def convert_dt(dt, to_fmt="%Y.%m.%d", from_fmt="%Y%m%d"):
    return DT.strptime(dt, from_fmt).strftime(to_fmt)
```

---

тесты:

```
In [118]: convert_dt("20150701")
Out[118]: '2015.07.01'

In [119]: convert_dt("20200806")
Out[119]: '2020.08.06'

In [120]: convert_dt("20200806", to_fmt="%d.%m.%Y")
Out[120]: '06.08.2020'

In [121]: convert_dt("2020-08-30 11:12:13", from_fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", to_fmt="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
Out[121]: '30.08.2020 11:12'
```

Answer (score 2):

С помощью регулярных выражений, найденное этим:

```
^(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d)$
```

заменить этим:

```
$1.$2.$3
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5a206